# Extraction of data using sql scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to extract the date from a list of employees and code are provided.

The list of employees and code are mapped into database into a temp table, S

The results of the temp table are then mapped into the tables below to extract the final output.

```sql
SELECT P.REFERENCENUMBER, PED.VALUE, PED.DATEFROM, PED.DATETO, PDD.DEDUCTIONDATACODE 
FROM [temptable] S
INNER JOIN PEOPLE P ON S.[EEnum] = P.REFERENCENUMBER
INNER JOIN DEDUCTIONDETAILS PDD ON S.DEDUCTIONCODE = PDD.DEDUCTIONDATACODE
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEDEDUCTIONS PED ON PDD.DEDUCTIONDETAILS_ID = PED.DEDUCTION 
  AND P.PEOPLE_ID = PED.PEOPLE_ID
```

I have to write a script which it will AVOID me to use the temp table to get the date from.

Comment: The question is quite un Clear. Can you please add more details to it. Like the Structure of your Temp table and how the data in the Temp Table is related to the Data in your main table( I mean the Keys) etc

Comment: Yes it is SQL server.

I don't have any details about the keys,
The List of employees that are mapped to the DB using the temp table has 2 columns, empno and datacode.

The results of the Temp table are then mapped with the joining tables to extract the final report.
My teacher asked me to solve this by writing a script to avoid using the temporary table to exract the DATEFROM

Comment: so basically you need to replace temp table with tables `empno` and `datacode`, right?  Whatever query you used to populate the temp table, just add it to your query above.

Comment: The data for empno and datacode are in an Excel.
This excel is then imported to the DB, using a temporary table in which the empno and datacode exists.

Comment: To avoid the use of a table (which is not a true "temp" table in the tsql sense) you need to query the excel file directly. Presumably that was a current subject covered by your teacher, so give it a try. Hints - [openquery and openrowset](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306397/how-to-use-excel-with-sql-server-linked-servers-and-distributed-querie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're avoiding the intermediary temp table, it sounds like you need a way to connect your Excel data directly to the database's data.  I dug around a little and this looks promising:

```sql
USE ImportFromExcel;
GO
SELECT * INTO Data_dq
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Temp\Data.xlsx', [Sheet1$]);
GO
```

[Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Maybe you can adapt this to your situation, something like:

```sql
SELECT P.REFERENCENUMBER, PED.VALUE, PED.DATEFROM, PED.DATETO, PDD.DEDUCTIONDATACODE 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Temp\Data.xlsx', [Sheet1$]) S
INNER JOIN PEOPLE P ON S.[EEnum] = P.REFERENCENUMBER
INNER JOIN DEDUCTIONDETAILS PDD ON S.DEDUCTIONCODE = PDD.DEDUCTIONDATACODE
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEDEDUCTIONS PED ON PDD.DEDUCTIONDETAILS_ID = PED.DEDUCTION 
  AND P.PEOPLE_ID = PED.PEOPLE_ID
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this feature, so I'm not sure if / how it works.  But it's worth a look.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, that was really helpful.

Comment: Great, happy to help :)  Were you able to get it to work?